# Static Route, Home Networking Problem

Tags: home-networking, windows-server-2008, static-routes

I have a home Windows 2008 Server with 2 Client PC's also attached to the network.

I also have 2 ISP's one of which is connected to the LAN switch and the other directly to the server. The server is attached to the LAN and it's own internet connection with 2 NIC's.

What I want to do is make it so that when using the 2 Client PC's traffic to specific IP's goes over the internet connection connected to the server rather than the standard LAN connection (just goes out through a router).

I created a static route for the IP in question that points to the LAN NIC of the server but if you traceroute it just stops there and times our after it hits the server.

What do I need to do on the server to forward the incoming traffic on that LAN NIC to its internet connection?

Any help greatly appreciated.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I think the quick and dirty solution is the enable internet connection sharing on your Server 2008 box.

Start -> ncpa.cpl -> select the interface that is connected to the ISP -> Sharing -> look further there.

The proper solution is to get IP forwarding software running on your Server 2008 box, essentially turning it into another router.  I've done this on Linux, and indeed many home routers are Linux-based, but for Windows, ICS is as far as I've gone.

Maybe try something like WinGate.